# data is not transformed well to querystring parameter when making api request using jQuery ajax call

Tags: json, jquery, query-string

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                async: false,
                url: "http://localhost:1234/api/",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: '{"id":"125"}',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data.toString());
                }
            });
```

When I call api using jQuery ajax call, data that I pass is not transformed well to querystring parameter.

here is what I see that's being called.

```
http://localhost:1234/api/?{%22id%22:%22125%22}
```

but when I pass data as an object for example, data: {"id":"125"} is works fine.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: content type is application/json so should I not have to pass as an json string?  then why should I specify content type?

Comment: You have specified `contentType: 'application/json'` and that's precisely what jQuery uses: JSON. As you told it. That's what you see in the query string: JSON. If this is not what you want to see in your query string then don't tell jQuery to use this contentType.

Answer (score 0):

You pass data as a js Object, and jQuery is converting it to JSON format, because you specify the JSON dataType.

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       async: false,
       url: "http://localhost:1234/api/",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       data: {"id": 125},
       success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.toString());
       }
  });
```

Comment: I have already tried that and it worked for me.  but trying to understand why I have to pass as an object not a JSON string even though my content type is json.

Comment: When you set content type to JSON, jQuery is converting your object to JSON, if you set it to HTML, you can pass a string and it won't be tranformed. It's easier to use !